# How to call a function when two separate HTML select options are chosen?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, onchange, addeventlistener

Can you please help me find a way to call a function when two separate select options are selected by the user? Please provide an answer using only Javascript. I am really struggling to get my head around this as I have only recently started learning. I want to show different results based on combinations of the two selects.

```
    <body>
  <header><div class="Heading"><h1>Shipper Calculator</h1></div><hr></header>
      <select id="Courier">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Courier</option>
        <option id="Marken">Marken</option>
        <option id="WorldCourier">World Courier</option>
        <option id="Quickstat">Quickstat</option>
        <option id="DHL">DHL</option>
      </select>
    <select id="Temperature">
      <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Temperature</option>
      <option id="ControlledAmbient_Refrigerated">15-25ºC / 2-8ºC</option>
      <option id="ControlleFrozen">-25ºC to -15º</option>
      <option id="DryIce">Dry Ice</option>
      <option id="Ambient">Ambient</option>
    </select>
```

The below is all I have for the Javscript so far. This works to show the alert when a certain option is selected but they do not work together. What I ideally want to say is for example.... if "Marken" and "Dry Ice" is selected then run a specific function.

```
document.getElementById("Courier").addEventListener("change", myFunction);
function myFunction() {
 var x = document.getElementById("Courier").selectedIndex;
 if (x == "3")
 alert("hey");
}

document.getElementById("Temperature").addEventListener("change", myFunction);
function myFunction() {
 var x = document.getElementById("Temperature").selectedIndex;
 if (x == "3")
 alert("hey");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

https://jsfiddle.net/470dxe2b/

```
 <header><div class="Heading"><h1>Shipper Calculator</h1></div><hr></header>
      <select id="Courier">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Courier</option>
        <option value="Marken">Marken</option>
        <option value="WorldCourier">World Courier</option>
        <option value="Quickstat">Quickstat</option>
        <option value="DHL">DHL</option>
      </select>
    <select id="Temperature">
      <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Temperature</option>
      <option value="ControlledAmbient_Refrigerated">15-25ºC / 2-8ºC</option>
      <option value="ControlleFrozen">-25ºC to -15º</option>
      <option value="DryIce">Dry Ice</option>
      <option value="Ambient">Ambient</option>
    </select>
```

Javascript

```
let temp = document.getElementById('Temperature');
let cour = document.getElementById('Courier');

temp.addEventListener('change', () => update());
cour.addEventListener('change', () => update());

function update(){
    dropDown1Value = cour.value;
    dropDown2Value = temp.value;

    switch (dropDown1Value + dropDown2Value) {
        case 'MarkenDryIce' :
                MarkenDryIce();
        break;
        default:
                console.log('Nothing to do');
        break;
    }
}

function MarkenDryIce(){
        alert('Marken + Dry Ice Selected');
}
```

Comment: This seems to be what I want. Is it possible for you to explain some of the code as I want to understand how it works? Don’t worry if you can’t I will try and look into it

Comment: Basically it adds event listeners to both drop downs that fire the **update** function. This takes the values from the 2 drop downs and combineds them together to make a key.

This key is then used to perform a lookup in the switch statement, so you can add more **case** statements for the combinations you need. There is also a default for when the values are not known, or not good.

when a statement key is matched, its runs in the code inside, which happens to be a function in this instance. but it can be any other logic you like.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please remember to upvote or choose a selected answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok a few things to note:

1. Change the option ids to value instead:

```html
<select id="Courier">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Courier</option>
    <option value="Marken">Marken</option>
    <option value="WorldCourier">World Courier</option>
    <option value="Quickstat">Quickstat</option>
    <option value="DHL">DHL</option>
</select>
<select id="Temperature">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Temperature</option>
    <option value="ControlledAmbient_Refrigerated">15-25ºC / 2-8ºC</option>
    <option value="ControlleFrozen">-25ºC to -15º</option>
    <option value="DryIce">Dry Ice</option>
    <option value="Ambient">Ambient</option>
</select>
```

2. Why not use one function to check both selects:

```js
document.getElementById("Courier").addEventListener("change", myFunction);

document.getElementById("Temperature").addEventListener("change", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    var y = document.getElementById("Courier");
    var x = document.getElementById("Temperature");
    if (y.value === "Marken" && x.value === "DryIce") {
        alert("hey");
    }
}
```

One problem that is probably causing you confusion is that you have named both of your functions the same name. This will cause unexpected results.  Make sure your functions have unique names. I mention this so that you can avoid the same issue in the future.

Comment: thank you! that was a copy and paste job! I will try your suggestion out tomorrow!

Comment: can you perform if statements after what you've suggested.... if (y.value === "Marken" && x.value === "Dry Ice") ? instead of the alert?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you are asking if you can replace the alert with some other logic.  If that is what you are asking then yes.  Replace `alert("hey")` with whatever logic you need.

Comment: I updated the code due to a typo. The second value in the if statement should be `"DryIce"` not `"Dry Ice"` (with a space) since it is referring to the value not the text.